# Whitespace in Python Code (PEP 8)

Tags: python, pep8, convention

Relatively minor question (more of a curiosity) having browsed through PEP 8 documentation, and looking through other people's code... is there a generally accepted preference or standard when it comes to the whitespace within each line of code? For example, would you go with the first or second below:

```
x=np.array([1,2,3,4])
y=x**2
```

OR

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
y = x ** 2
```

I see a lot of both on this site and in other work and I was just curious as to what the majority of people approve of or prefer to see and use.

Comment: What you ask is specifically covered in PEP8: [Whitespace in expressions and statements](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements).

Comment: Definitely the second. People who write it as the first way are the bane of my existence. Btw, this will likely be closed as off topic for being highly subjective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the [PEP8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) under the [Whitespace in Expressions and Statements - Other recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations) section :

> Always surround these binary operators with a single space on either side: assignment ( = ), augmented assignment ( += , -= etc.), comparisons ( == , < , > , != , <> , <= , >= , in , not in , is , is not ), Booleans ( and , or , not ).

So the second is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

On stackoverflow, users generally write sample code: often not formatted…

Programmers should follow the PEP8: [Whitespace in Expressions and Statements](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements)

See also: [The Pocoo Style Guide](http://www.pocoo.org/internal/styleguide/), topic "Expressions and Statements".

In real world, we use IDE, like [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), which format and check the code for you.

Also, note that lots of tools, notably [flake8](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/index.html) can check your code.